# How to increase alphabetic variable - Batch

Tags: batch-file

I was able to increase the number variable:

```
 SET /a Y=0
 SET /a Y+=1
 ECHO %Y% = 1
```

But I want to "increase" the variable with letters.
Ex:

```
SET Y=A
SET Y+=1
ECHO %Y% = B
```

Anyway to do something like this in Batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with a sort of fake pointer.

```
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Letters=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Set I=25
SET Y=!Letters:~%I%,1!
Echo Y=%Y%
SET /A I+=1,I=I %% 26
SET Y=!Letters:~%I%,1!
Echo Y=%Y%
```

To have the algorythm continue with A again after reaching Z, you've to calculate the modulus 26

```
Y=Z
Y=A
```